# SQL count counting all the data, but not all rows showing up

Tags: sql, mysql, count

I am doing some SQL exercises and I wanted to print a list of cities and a count for each one.

This is my table:

```
patient_id  INT
first_name  TEXT
last_name   TEXT
gender      CHAR(1)
birth_date  DATE
city        TEXT
province_id CHAR(2)
allergies   TEXT
height      INT
weight      INT
```

This is my query:

```
select city, count(*) as count
from patients
```

And it returns this result:

```
city   | count
Barrie | 4530
```

I was expecting a row with each city and only then the count value "4530".

Why is this happening? Shouldn't it be selecting all of the cities since I am not filtering anything?

I am doing some training exercises on https://www.sql-practice.com/

Comment: The query is invalid. You are running MySQL in cheat mode, which suppresses the error message you should get. Always have the sql_mode contain ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in MySQL. As is, MySQL silently turns your `select city` into `select any_value(city)`, i.e. picks one city arbitrarily. The cheat mode was the default in old MySQL versions. It isn't in newer versions, which indicates that you are running an outdated MySQL version and should probably upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is missing a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT city, COUNT(*)
FROM patients
GROUP BY city;
```

In general, the GROUP BY is followed by a list of column names. The result of the query will be one row for each unique combination of values for the columns specified after GROUP BY.

As to why you get the result you did. In most implementations of SQL your query would result in an error message because standard SQL does not allow unaggregated columns in the SELECT list unless they are also in the GROUP BY. It is a "feature" of MySQL that it will run such a query but the value in the city column in this case is logically undefined - you will see one arbitrary value for the city column because you asked for it but the count is correctly made across the entire table because there is no GROUP BY. In standard SQL, the following query gives the count of rows for the whole table because there is no GROUP BY but the COUNT function implies that the aggregation is required across all the rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM patients;
```

Unless your intention is specifically to learn MySQL/Mariadb then you may find it easier to familiarise yourself with the standard behaviour first by using a different SQL DBMS.

Comment: Thanks for that, i had already realised that if i added a group by it would work, my question is maybe more of a teorical one i guess?? In another words, why is it that the result of :  SELECT city FROM patients is a list of all cities but my first querry is not a list of all cities with a second column containing the number 4530?

Comment: @Diogo, great. Please upvote and/or mark the question as answered when you are ready.